# Bit operation of extract flags into 24 bit integer

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I saw a line in xen's  kernel code (file: xen/include/asm-x86/x86_64/page.h), but cannot understand why they are doing this:

```
/* Extract flags into 24-bit integer, or turn 24-bit flags into a pte mask. */                                                                      
#define get_pte_flags(x) (((int)((x) >> 40) & ~0xFFF) | ((int)(x) & 0xFFF))                                                                         
#define put_pte_flags(x) (((intpte_t)((x) & ~0xFFF) << 40) | ((x) & 0xFFF))
```

As to

```
#define get_pte_flags(x) (((int)((x) >> 40) & ~0xFFF) | ((int)(x) & 0xFFF))
```

I understand `((int)(x) & 0xFFF)` will extract the last 24 bits of x, but why they need the first part `((int)((x) >> 40) & ~0xFFF)` ?

As to

```
  #define put_pte_flags(x) (((intpte_t)((x) & ~0xFFF) << 40) | ((x) & 0xFFF))
```

I'm lost at the purpose of `((intpte_t)((x) & ~0xFFF) << 40)`. It should be 0 in my opinion. Then why do we need it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look twice at their code. Because it took me a minute to realize that 0xFFF is not 24 bits, it's only 12 bits. So take an example 64 bit input: `0xAABBCCDDEEFF1122`. Shift it right by 40, and you get `0x0000000000AABBCC`. `~0xFFF` is shorthand in this case for `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF000`. `And` them together, and you get `0x0000000000AAB000`. So basically, they grabbed the top 12 bits and moved them down. Then they `or` that with the bottom 12 bits. So they end up with `0x0000000000AAB122`.

The other half does the opposite, takes 24 bits at the bottom, cuts them in half and puts 12 at the top and 12 at the bottom.

Comment: If the topmost bit was set, will the right shift drag the sign bit along (arithmetic shift) or left-fill with 0 bits (logical shift)? If the former, the shift could give you 0xFFFFFFFFFFAABBCC. Would this depend on whether the original int was signed or unsigned? A brief look at some other SO threads suggest that it's _usually_ done arithmetic shift. You would have to guarantee that the sign bit is always clear (0).

Comment: Hi @PhilPerry, the x has to been unsigned int, so it will be logic right shift. But thank you very much for pointing this pitfall out. :)

Comment: you need ~(0xFFFULL) to get 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF000

Answer (score 1):

`0xFFF` is not 24 one-bits, it's only 12.

Knowing this, you'll see that the purpose of `get_pte_flags` is to move the top 12 bits into position 12-24, like so:

```
xxxxxxxx xxxx0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000yyyy yyyyyyyy
```

becomes

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 xxxxxxxx xxxxyyyy yyyyyyyy
```

Of course, `put_pte_flags` does the inverse, moving the bits back to the most significant position.

Answer (score 0):

Think 64 bit.

On a 32 bit system the result would be 0, of course.
But, when you shift 24 bit 40 bits left, you have

```
xxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy zzzzzzzz 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

which is a valid 64 bit value.